# Can't figure out necessary and sufficient conditions for showing that a cubic curve can be transformed to the quadratic one

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, curves, bezier-curve

As i posted before [Can a cubic Bezier curve be a quadratic one if two control points are equal from the cubic one?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2759306/can-a-cubic-bezier-curve-be-a-quadratic-one-if-two-control-points-are-equal-from). I've got some great answers and they helped but i found another solution which involves matrix approach. Recalling the problem, which says if the transformation of cubic curve to quadratic (where two control points are equal) is possible. So i used degree reduction.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1/3 & 2/3 & 0 \\
0 & 2/3 & 1/3 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
b_0 \\
b_1 \\
b_2
 \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
c_0 \\
c_1 \\
c_2 \\
c_3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
the equation $$DB=C$$ then multiplied by $D^T$
$$D^TDB=D^TC$$
then i get $B=(D^TD)^{-1}D^TC$. After that i found fundamental system of solutions of $D^T$
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
  1 & 1/3 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 2/3 & 2/3 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 1/3 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right] $$
it gives the solution $(-1, 3, -3, 1)$ or $$-c_0+3c_1-3c_2+c_3=0$$
this condition tells **if the points of the cubic curve satisfy this condition, then transformation of cubic to quadratic is possible**. But as from my original condition of the problem (two control points of the cubic are equal) which means $c_1=c_2$ and thus it leads to $c_0=c_3$ (as condition $-c_0+3c_1-3c_2+c_3=0$ needs to be satisfied). It means cubic actually transforms to the linear curve (as we got the pairs $c_1=c_2$ and $c_0=c_3$). So as i figured $c_1=c_2$ and $c_0=c_3$ is actually sufficient condition for showing that cubic transforms to linear and it's impossible to transform it to quadratic with this condition. So i can't figure out how to find necessary condition and i'm also stuck for finding necessary and sufficient conditions for showing that transformation from cubic to quadratic via this $-c_0+3c_1-3c_2+c_3=0$ is possible. I will be grateful if somebody helps me with finding it

Answer (score 1):

[My answer to your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2759306/can-a-cubic-bezier-curve-be-a-quadratic-one-if-two-control-points-are-equal-from?noredirect=1&lq=1) already showed that the cubic is a quadratic if and only if 
$$
-c_0+3c_1-3c_2+c_3=0
$$
You have managed to prove this yourself, now (though it seems to me that your method is much more complicated than mine).

Now suppose that $c_1=c_2$, which is apparently what you mean by "two control points are equal". Substituting this in the equation above, we see that we have a quadratic if and only if
$$
-c_0+c_3=0
$$
In other words, a cubic with $c_1=c_2$ is a quadratic if and only if $c_0 = c_3$. In other words, the necessary and sufficient condition that you're seeking is $c_0 = c_3$.

The equation of the curve is then
$$
P(t) = (1-t)^3c_0 + 3t(1-t)^2c_1 + 3t^2(1-t)c_1 + t^3c_0
$$
A little algebra shows that this can be reduced to
$$
P(t0 = (1-t)^2 c_0 + 2t(1-t)\Bigl(\tfrac32 c_1 - \tfrac12 c_0 \Bigr) +t^2 c_0
$$
This is a **quadratic** Bezier curve with control points $c_0$, 
$\tfrac32 c_1 - \tfrac12 c_0$, $c_0$.

This curve happens to lie within the straight line between $c_0$ and $c_1$. In fact
as $t$ increases from $0$ to $1,$ the curve point $P(t)$ makes an out-and-back trip from $c_0$ to $\tfrac14(c_0+3c_1)$, and back to $c_0$ again.

So, some people might say that it's a "linear" curve. But, usually, a "linear" curve is defined to be one whose degree is equal to $1$. By that definition, our curve is not linear, it is quadratic, because its degree is equal to $2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. But still i can't understand this one, if $c_1=c_2$ and apparently $c_0=c_3$ how can it be the quadratic one if it's actually the linear curve? And to prove it let's say $P(t)=(1-t)^3c_0 + 3t(1-t)^2c_1 + 3t^2(1-t)c_1 + t^3c_0$ then we can say $c_0[(1-t)^3 + t^3] + c_1[3t^2(1-t) + 3t(1-t)^2]$ from which goes $u=[3t^2(1-t) + 3t(1-t)^2]$ and $1-u=[(1-t)^3 + t^3]$ and this actually gives us the linear curve not quadratic. $$B(t)=(1-u)c_0 + uc_1$$. But maybe i'm wrong

Comment: By definition, a linear curve has degree $=1$. Our curve has degree $=2$. Our curve lies within a straight line, but that doesn't mean that it's "linear".